# Compute the number of sublists each term appears in the list

Tags: python

I am trying to compute the number of sublists each term appears in the list but I am stuck at the very first step. For example,

```
collection = [['a','b','b','c','d','e','f'],['b','b','d','f']]
```

It should return me (a,1) (b,2) (c,1) (d,2) (e,1) (f,2)

I am able to iterate through the collection to print everything out

```
[item for sublist in collection for item in sublist]
```

The issue I have is that I'm not sure how I can receive the count and go to the next loop after finding an occurence.

```
[item for sublist in collection for item in sublist if 'b' == item]
```

This returns me

```
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

Id like it to return me 2. This is how I envisioned the code to be.

```
count = [count++ for sublist in collection for item in sublist if 'b' == item]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten `collection` as a set and then find the counts:

```
collection = [['a','b','b','c','d','e','f'],['b','b','d','f']]
c = {i for b in collection for i in b}
final_results = [(i, sum(i in x for x in collection)) for i in c]
```

Output:

```
[('c', 1), ('d', 2), ('f', 2), ('e', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: I often forget you can sum bools. I rather prefer `sum(1 for x in xs if pred(x))` to `sum(pred(x) for x in xs)` but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sum` and a generator expression that gives `1` if the element is in the sublist.

```
import itertools

collection = [['a','b','b','c','d','e','f'],['b','b','d','f']]

all_letters = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(collection))
# or write them out by hand
# all_letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}

result = [(ch, sum(1 for sublst in collection if ch in sublst)) for
          ch in all_letters]
# [('e', 1), ('d', 2), ('f', 2), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('c', 1)]
# or some other order, since sets are orderless.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need global statistics like that its probably better to use a `dictionary`

```
counts = {}
for sublist in collection:
    for element in sublist:
        if element not in data:
            counts[element] = 0
            for sublist in collection:
                if element in sublist:
                    counts[element] += 1
```

Maybe not the most efficient, but gets the job done.